# JSDoc Type property as function parameter is not valid

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, jsdoc

I am working on a javascript project (with VSCode) and we use `JSDoc` and the eslint rule [`valid-jsdoc`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/valid-jsdoc).
I have an object type which has some properties, as an example:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Project
 * @property {string} id
 * @property {string} name
 */
```

In the code I am able to use the type `Project['id']` ex:

```js
/**
 * @param {Project['id']} projectId
 */
function myFunction(projectId) {}
```

It recognises the type `Project['id']` and indicates it is a `string` when I hoover it.

I would like to force people to write JSDoc, so I want to use the eslint rule `valid-jsdoc`. However, the rule doesn't know the type `Project['id']` and highlight the jsdoc with the error

```
JSDoc syntax error
```

It doesn't show any error if I use

```js
/**
 * @param {Project} project
 */
function myFunction(project) {}
```

or

```js
/**
 * @param {string} projectId
 */
function myFunction(projectId) {}
```

I think it is a pity to not be able to use `Project['id']` and use `string` instead because of this rule, it is less explicite and sometimes (for more complex object) it might be troublesome.

Is there anyway to achieve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: would `@param {Project.id} projectId` work instead?

Comment: I tried, but this is not even accepted by the JSDoc instead :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Project - A new project
 * @property {String} id - The Project id
 * @property {String} name - The Project name
 */
```

You can now use as it as used below

```
/**
 * @param {Project} project
 */
function myFunction(project) { 
    var id = project.id // hover over this
}
```

Comment: Hello, this is not what I'm looking for, I want to indicate in the JSDoc that my function take `Project['id']` as a parameter (and not `Project` or `string`)

Comment: Well i don't know if jsdoc has a syntax for that, but its worth trying and researching

Comment: I think there is a confusion in how you understood my question. JSDoc already has a syntax, you can write `Project['id']`. However the eslint rule `valid-jsdoc` which is used to force people to write JSDoc doesn't support this syntax and highlight it as a `JSDoc syntax error` (but it is an error in the rule who doesn't manage to parse the valid JSDoc)

Comment: Now i get your question, why not just use plain JSDoc without the eslint stuff

Comment: As I have written in the question, it is to force people to write proper JSDoc